# How to style with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to use style attribute for JavaScript. But, apparently, I was doing something wrong with it. I am new in JavaScript so a general idea about `style` attribute for JavaScript would be great. I want to change the  place, color and text-decoration etc. of JavaScript elements. I thought that declaring style attribute for div `changeMe` in HTML will be applied for the JavaScript. Because, JavaScript takes id of it. I wanted to use all of the style attributes that are in the div. Where am I missing? Here is my attempt to do it:

```
<div id="changeMe" style="position: absolute;text-decoration: none; 
                          color: white;right:43%; top: 90px;">
    <a href="home.php" >Go to homepage</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var testElement = document.getElementById("changeMe");
var text = "aaa".document.getElementById("changeMe");
text.style.textDecoration = "none"; //I changed style here too because first did not       
//work.

check.onfocus= function()
{   
    testElement.innerHTML = text.link("index.php");;
}
```

Please help me understand the structure.I am stuck.Thanks

Comment: I wanted to use all style attributes of div "changeME" for javascript links(text.link)But it did not work.How can i do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: What is `check`? What do you think `"aaa".document` should be? What do you think `text` should be?

Comment: I think it would greatly benefit you to visit http://learn.appendto.com/lessons and watch all of their free lessons (of if you are time strapped just watch the JavaScript ones and save the jQuery ones for later).  You'll get a good understanding of JavaScript from them which will either help you solve your own issue or at the very least it will help you formulate a better question to ask on this site.

Comment: @user893970 — you can't. The style attribute only lets you style the element to which it is applied. It is a very limited and ugly tool, which is why real stylesheets are preferred (the [selector syntax](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/) is very powerful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JavaScript will error here:

> `var text = "aaa".document.getElementById("changeMe");`

…since `"aaa"` is a string and strings do not have a `document` property. The rest of the script won't execute.

If you fixed that line, then:

> `text.style.textDecoration = "none";`

… would have no effect. The **text-decoration** is part of the **link's** style, not the div's.

You need to style the `<a>` element. If you really want to get to it via JS then you can:

```
testElement.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
```

But you would probably be better off just using a stylesheet:

```
#changeMe a { text-decoration: none; }
```

But make sure you do something else to make it clear that the piece of non-underlined text is a link.

Answer (score 0):

Something definitely fishy here.

```
var text = "aaa".document.getElementById("changeMe");

// Without those "aaa"
var text = document.getElementById("changeMe");

// To change the <a> style inside the 'changeMe' <div>
var alinks = text.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<alinks.length; i++) {
  alinks[i].style.textDecoration = "none";
}
```

[Here it is in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/TZPaN/)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to style the `div` but you need to apply your `text-decoration` and `color` styles to the `a` tag itself for it to take effect.

All of this can easily be done with cascading style sheets instead, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("changeMe").firstChild.style.textDecoration = "none";
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Evyq/